Make a cell signal heat map of remote location
I work and camp at a remote backwoods location in Eastern Ontario (200 acres). I’ve noticed that I can get a weak data signal at some spots on the tops of hills. I would like to make a map of the signal strength so that I can determine where the strongest signal is; the Bell coverage map is not detailed enough.
Is there a way to generate a cell signal heat map using my android phone?

Do you mean "Generate a heatmap by visiting all the hilltops and observing signal strengths there" or "Generate a heatmap from the tower locations and power levels and an elevation map of the area"? The former is practical, but slow; the latter is quick, but may not match observed reality. In either case, the signal you can get from distant towers may vary with the weather and season.

@JohnDallman I meant, "Generate a heatmap by visiting all the hilltops and observing signal strengths there." Good point about the weather and season affecting reception.

@JohnDallman Any idea how much the leaves being off the trees might affect reception?

I don't know how large the leaves effect is, but I'd expect there to be one. If you're going to visit the hilltops, do you really need a heatmap? Simply knowing which hilltop is best seems like enough.
